# Cooldowns, reactions and few more problems with discord.py

Tags: python, pycharm, bots, discord.py

Im creating a discord bot in python and i have few problems i would like to get a help with.

**1. I would like to know how to add cooldown on a command. So for example someone will use a command and everyone will not be able to use the same command for some amount of time.**

Here is one of my commands, i tried using time module at the end of the code, it works but you are not able to use any other commands. Any advice ?

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    chat = bot.get_channel(792030436523114496)
    if msg.content.startswith("Who"):
        if msg.channel.id != channel:
            return
        await chat.send("You are " + msg.author.name)
        time.sleep(60)
```

**2. Second problem is similiar to the first one, but instead of adding cooldown on a command. I would like to add cooldown on a question.**

Here is my code on a question and i want to add cooldown so people will try to answer the question but they will be able to do it only, lets say, for 30 seconds, then the question will just end if nobody had answered it.

```
if msg.content.startswith("Question"):
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    await chat.send("1+1 ?")
    await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda msg: msg.content == "2")
    await chat.send("Good work " + msg.author.mention)
```

**3. The third one is kinda tricky, its about that bot would be able to add reactions on its own message.**

Here you can see a picture how it should looks like. I want the bot to add reactions on its own message and then if there is any method when someone click on A, something happens.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B53gM.png)

**4. And the last problem is quite simple.**

Here we can take the same code from the first problem. To execute this command, people must write Who but i want to make that people can also write wHo, whO, WHo and so on regardless on uppercases or lowercases.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    chat = bot.get_channel(792030436523114496)
    if msg.content.startswith("Who"):
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please keep in mind this is not really a site to ask for other people to code your solution (very sorry if I misunderstood your question here) but rather to ask for help with a concrete problem when you tried coding it and got stuck. You also seem to have 4 separate questions that would be better off as such. Maybe you could just focus on the first one, and elaborate more on what exact code changes you tried and how that didn't work out as you thought in full detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `discord.py` has a built-in support for cooldowns, here an example

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 6.0, commands.BucketType.guild) # rate, per, BucketType
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

2. This question is kinda tricky, you'd need to use a cog and `commands.CooldownMapping` (There's no docs about it so I can't give you the link)

```py
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._cd = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 6.0, commands.BucketType.guild) # Change accordingly


    def get_ratelimit(self, message):
        """Returns the ratelimit left"""
        bucket = self._cd.get_bucket(message)
        return bucket.update_rate_limit()
   

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.lower() == "question":
            # Getting the ratelimit
            retry_after = self.get_ratelimit(message)
            if retry_after is None:
                # You're not ratelimited, send the question
                await message.channel.send("Question")
            
            else:
                # You're ratelimited, don't send the question
                await message.channel.send(f"You need to wait {retry_after} seconds to get another question")


bot.add_cog(SomeCog(bot))
```

(This was heavily inspired by one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230432/cooldown-mapping-discord-py/65232114#65232114))

3. This question is a really easy one, simply use `Message.add_reaction` method

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("This is the message I want to add the reaction to")
    await message.add_reaction("")
```

*Note: For default reactions the reaction must be a unicode, to get it `\:emoji:`*

4. You can use the `str.lower` method

```py
>>> "HeLlO".lower()
"hello"
```

```py
if message.content.lower().starswith("who"):
    # ...
```

**If you're using `discord.Client` none of this is gonna work, you need to use `commands.Bot`**

#### Reference:

- [`commands.cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)
- [`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20add_reac#discord.Message.add_reaction)
- [`String.lower`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower)

*I answered your questions cause I know the answer to all of them, next time try to separate each question and focus more on each of them, what have you tried, what is the result, what is the expected result...*